# C# OpenVpnConnect Code Ok in Win7 But Not Work In Windows Server

Tags: c#, console-application

Hello I Wrote C# Console Application For Disconnect From OpenVpnConnect
My Command in my C# Code is :

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("OpenVPNConnect.exe --disconnect-shortcut=1628621371733");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
```

In Windows 7 Run Ok
When Run in Windows Server 2019 Run But Not Work
I Tested Run As Administrator
And My Account Member Of Administrators Group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem Is OS Windws Server 2019
I Tested My Code in Windows Server 2016 and 2019 Another Location Is Good
After Clean Install Windows Server 2019 My Problem is Solved